# Linking SQL Tables - Issue

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to link two SQL tables together, both the tables have data entered in them through HTML/PHP forms.
The first table is where the user enters all their details into a form (called system), and the second table is for where a user fills out another form for booking (called users). How do I link these tables together? To show the users booking(s).
I don't know how to get the booking table/form to echo out the user's username into the second table to link them together?
I understand that this does not make sense but would really appreciate some help!!!

Here is the first table's SQL for creating a user account:
And, here is the SQL for creating a booking?:

```
</form>
</body>
</html> 

  <br></br>


    </div>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that links what the user entered for the booking form (system table) to the SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to query them together a join should do the trick.

```
SELECT users.user_first, users.user_last, users.user_email, system.* FROM system INNER users JOIN ON users.user_uid = system.user_uid
```

In order to store the user_uid value in the system table you need to add a hidden input in your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['u_id']; ?>">
```

then in your php add

```
$user_uid = $_POST['uid'];
```

and insert it when you run your insert query.

```
INSERT INTO system (date, time, table_layout, user_uid) VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$table_layout', '$user_uid');
```

Just make sure that your table actually has that column. Once that value is available you should be able to run the above join query.

Comment: Hello! Thats the issue, theres nothing in the details.user_id, how do I get for the data to enter it? When the user is asked to fill out the 'details' table form, it does not ask for the user to enter their user_id, so that is left blank. How do I fill it in? (hope this makes sense?!)

Comment: in the form add a hidden value with the user id

Comment: Do I echo it out or?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="user_uid" value="<?php echo $user_uid; ?>">`

Comment: then just add that in when you initially insert the values

Comment: Omg you're a genius, where would I put this piece of code? In the coding page where I link to the SQL database, or the page where the user is told to fill out the form?

Comment: the hidden input goes inside the form that the user is filling out

Comment: There is no need for that. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: it would help if you showed your html and the php code that is inserting the data

Comment: @LucasDesouza Do you think you could have a look at my code or?

Comment: Add it your question so that when its solved it can help others in the future

Comment: @LucasDesouza I've updated it with the code that links the form to the SQL for the booking form

Comment: I think there is still some missing code. Where is the insert query into details? also where is the html form that the user is filling out

Comment: Is the table name details or system? I don't see an insert into details at all.

Comment: @LucasDesouza Oh sorry! The tables name is 'system', not 'details'!!! I'm so sorry about that, I have also included the code you suggested and thought it would work - but sadly not. The system is constantly checking if the user is logged in with 'u_id', (which is the ID in the users table), and I thought that would work by getting the PHP to enter the 'u_i'd into the SQL but sadly not.

Comment: @LucasDesouza Hi again, I'm afraid that didn't work :/ Whenever I   <?php

 echo $_SESSION['u_id'];
 
 ?> to show the id number, it does work, i just dont understand why it will not enter a different database!!

Comment: then you need to echo that in the hidden input's value field. see my new edit.

Comment: @LucasDesouza oh my goodness!! you beautiful person, you got it to work!! thank you so much!! i could cry

Comment: @LucasDesouza thank you so much, you're truly amazing, thank you for solving the issue I've had for a while!!! if you're pursuing computing, you're going to be great at it

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768772/getting-sql-to-check-availability new problem!

Answer (score 1):

Two tables can be "linked" together using JOIN. If you want to list the bookings (rows in the details table), with some user information, you can use LEFT OUTER JOIN or INNER JOIN. (The difference is that with LEFT OUTER JOIN you get all the bookings even if some of them don't have a user. With INNER JOIN you get only the bookings where there exists a corresponding row in users.)

If a column has the same name in two different tables, you can use users.user_uid and details.user_uid to refer to them.

```
SELECT details.*, user.email, user.first, user.last
FROM details LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON user.user_id = details.user_uid;
```

Then you maybe want to add a WHERE or ORDER BY and perhaps a LIMIT.

In the users table, there is a user_id (INT) and a user_uid (VARCHAR). The details table has a user_uid (INT). In the example, I was assuming that the user_uid in the details table corresponds to the user_id in the users table because these are both INT. You might want to change the name of some column to make it less confusing. Let's assume you want to rename users.user_uid to "username".

Also, you should add a unique index on the user_id and username, assuming that you want both of them to be unique. For the INT, I suggest you make this the primary key with automatically incrementing numbers and the username, just a unique key:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ... ,
  username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ...
);
```

In the details table you probably also want to make the ID a PRIMARY KEY with AUTO_INCREMENT.

A unique key guarantees that there are no duplicates and it also makes lookups on these columns efficient.

Comment: This is really important. I didn't include it in the answer because I can't help but think that the problem roots are more basic, like understanding the problem and the solution (apart from knowing sql)

Comment: the issue is that there is nothing inside of the details.user_uid because the user is not asked to enter it in the form.

Comment: In that case, you have to first INSERT the user, then user $mysqli->insert_id to get the id from the last INSERT. This requires that the id is a PRIMARY KEY with AUTO_INCREMENT. Now you have an uid to insert into the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. You have two tables, one with user data (users), and one with booking data (details). A "details" row contains an ID of the user linked to that particular row.
Once you know, at least, the ID of the booking, you can get the id of the user like this:

```
SELECT user_uid FROM details WHERE ID = @specificBookingID
```

Once you know the user id you can get the user data:

```
SELECT * FROM users where user_uid = @retrievedUserID
```

You can do it in one query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users where user_uid IN (SELECT user_uid FROM details WHERE ID = @specificBookingID)
```

Comment: He doesn't know how to add the user_uid into the details table so that column is empty and your sub query would be empty.

Comment: The issue is, one user can have multiple data in the booking details (details table), so I don't understand how to link it because surely the details ID will be constantly changing?

Comment: One user can "have" multiple bookings. That means that there will be multiple rows in "details" which will share the same value for "user_uid".

Comment: What do you mean by this "surely the details ID will be constantly changing"?

Comment: @LucasDesouza I feel like there are multiple things he has to resolve. Not only that. But yes, this is not just an SQL question.

Comment: He is worried because your query is searching for a specific id in details table. But thats not really the issue. The problem he is trying to solve is when creating the record in the details table he is not adding the user_uid so he can't query it.

Comment: Right there would probably be more questions after he solves that

Comment: **she, I'm struggling

Comment: I feel like I've answered the next question @hello123 will have

Comment: oops sorry about that

Comment: @hello123 I have a tip for situations like this. Take a chill pill and read some theory about table logic and a ton of examples! At least on Wikipedia. Something to get your mind out of the gutter. It will help the knowledge sink a little bit deeper each time. Is this homework?

Comment: @NicoBerrogorry Yeah sadly it is, I'm so close to finishing but I just need my tables to be linked :/

Comment: Alright. Let me find you some material. Do you have time to study before you finish it, or is the limit date in 2 hours?

Comment: This page is very good, I recommend you take the time to go through each of the examples. It should take you no more than a few days to complete the reading if you have to do other stuff.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @NicoBerrogorry Hi, I've already read through that and I'm still struggling :/ do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ok you tell me what are you supposed to do (what's the task/subtask), and I will try to tell you what you need to do (without doing it myself, since its homework)

Comment: @NicoBerrogorry Basically, I'm making a booking system for my project but I'm completely in the dark with it, hence why I'm struggling. I want to have the two tables connected, have the user connected to their table booking, but no idea how to link them? I have 'user_uid', in the users sign up SQL table form, and placed 'user_uid' in the booking form SQL table too, but theres nothing in the booking form 'user_uid', as I have no asked the user to enter it. How can I get the two tables to join?

Comment: OK. First of all: There is no such thing as "getting the tables to join". This happens only in your head. What you can do when you have two tables A and B in a relationship of 1 from A to n from B (n meaning anything from 0 to positive infinity), is add a UNIQUE ID column to table A, and a column A_ID to table B. This will allow multiple rows(n) from table B to refer to a single(1) row in A. There are only tables and rows, as there are only 1s and 0s in a computer, the "link" is in your head, in the abstraction of the problem. But you MUST fill A_ID for every insertion in B.

Comment: You can use a hidden field, any sort of cache, session tokens, any means to know who (what user) is currently booking (inserting into B or "bookings"). But you must know the user ID beforehand and provide it yourself, there is no way it will insert itself.